# how to localize new posts in asp.net...?

Tags: web, asp.net

I am doing my final year project and have decided to make a website in asp.net. For that I'll be using Micrsoft Visual Studio 2008. I'm making a Real ESTATE properties website. I want to know how to localize or create new posts in asp.net( like in WORDPRESS) and also when I hit SEARCH it should search for the desired keyword or the searched post.

If post is not possible then it should display pages...

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you having a specific problem?  Stackoverflow isn't a place to post "I want to do this: tell me how." questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net is just the language not the CMS. You have to install a CMS for blogs such as dotnetnuke or BlogEngine.net